# creating two segue from single tableview in Swift

Tags: swift, segue

The only way I know to easily create as segue is by dragging from the the source tableview and dropping it into the destination controller.  That works fine.

Now, I have created a condition that checks the selected index content or identifier and will redirect it to a specific controller based on that value.  The problem I find is that I can only select one segue at a time.  If I create another segue route, the previous segue connection will vanish.

What is the best way to establish this task? or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is when a cell is selected, check the value, and perform the segue you want:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if someCondition {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segue1", sender: indexPath)
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segue2", sender: indexPath)
    }
}
```

In the storyboard, you create multiple segues from the controller that has the table to the others, just make sure to name them the same as in your code. You can have multiple segues on the same controller, as long as you give them unique identifiers.